# Nodejs serve static image with httpdispatcher

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using  [httpdispatcher](https://github.com/alberto-bottarini/httpdispatcher) and want to serve static images. I have an /resources folder in app folder. and have below code. I tried http://localhost:3000/resources/abc.jpg  to get image but didnt get any response. any idea?

```
var http = require('http');
var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
 dispatcher.setStatic('resources');
 dispatcher.setStaticDirname('.');

const PORT=3000; 

function handleRequest(request, response){
      try {
        console.log(request.url);
        dispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


dispatcher.onGet("/page1", function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var response={"res":'Page One id: ' + req.params.id};
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});    


dispatcher.onPost("/post1", function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var response={"res":'Got Post Data appId: '+JSON.parse(req.body).appId};
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});

    dispatcher.onError(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end("NOT FOUND");
    });



var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);


server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: Did you create the server? You can set up the dispatcher, but you still need to create a server and bind it to a port using `http.createServer` and `listen`. See the [`README`](https://github.com/alberto-bottarini/httpdispatcher/blob/master/README.md) (towards the end)

Comment: Yeap I create the server and I got response from get and post requests  but not get response from image requests @BrandonAnzaldi

Comment: @nikinci Can you please show the routes in your server?

Comment: @SkArif edited question

Comment: This actually appears to be a bug with the package itself. Because it doesn't incorporate the current directory into the `path.join`, it ends up with a file path that looks like this: `.resources/originst.jpg`.

Comment: Further inspection reveals that they break absolute paths actually. So, it'll take a bit of finagling to get this package to work properly in serving static directories in its current state. In order to do a relative path, you must start the staticDirName to start with `/`, and work with that as a relative path. You may also wish to open an issue with the author/create a pull request to fix it if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work my comments into an answer, `httpdispatcher`'s current static asset implementation is broken for a few reasons.

1. Improper path parsing. (`.` isn't properly handled, and is joined poorly in the code) Offending line: `var filename = "." + require('path').join(this.staticDirname, url.pathname);`
2. Doesn't exclude the specified resource url from the pathname it checks. So even if you specify `.` as the static directory, but specify `resources` as the URL handler, the static directory structure must include a resources folder, or the URL must include `..`, which seems like a ripe avenue for directory traversal attacks.

There are probably better packages for your use case that presently work, <del>but it's worth reporting these flaws to the module author.</del> Edit: Looks like there are already issues for the [path traversal vulnerability](https://github.com/alberto-bottarini/httpdispatcher/issues/8), and the [directory resolution](https://github.com/alberto-bottarini/httpdispatcher/issues/13).

At present, you could either handle the routing manually through matching in an HTTP Server handler, or you could use a different library. To name a few, [Express](https://npmjs.com/package/express), [Diet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diet) with [diet-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diet-static), etc.

EDIT: It appears that these issues may have been resolved as of `1.1.0` as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/alberto-bottarini/httpdispatcher/issues/13).

Comment: Thanks @Brandon I decided to use Express

Comment: Glad to help @nikinci :)